# How to distinguish between "0" and NULL in perl?

Tags: perl

Here we are looking for the string "reftext" in the given file. The line next to this contains a string with 3 integers. So we are extracting them in `@all_num`. We are printing the value of `@all_num[2]` only if is not NULL. But the logic used here doesn't print `@all_num[2]` even if it has 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open( READFILE, "<myfile.txt" );
@list        = <READFILE>;
$total_lines = scalar @list;

for ( $count = 0; $count < $total_lines; $count++ ) {
    if (@list[ $count =~ /reftext/ )
        {
            @all_num = @list[ $count + 1 ] =~ /(\d+)/g;
            if ( @all_num[2] != NULL ) {
                print "@all_num[2]\n";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `use strict` and `use warnings` at top of your program after _shebang_ line.

Comment: And it would be more helpful if you can provide _myfile.txt_ data.

Comment: There's no NULL in perl. Use undef when you mean "no value".

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fvals = (
 [ i => undef ],
 [ j => 0 ],
 [ k => "" ],
);

for my $r (@fvals) {
  my ($k, $v) = @$r;
  if    (!defined($v)) { print "$k is undef\n"; }
  elsif (!length($v))  { print "$k is empty string\n"; }
  # elsif (!$v)        { print "$k is zero\n"; }
  # recognizes zero value in "0.0" or "0E0" notation
  elsif ($v == 0)      { print "$k is zero\n"; }
}
```

output

```
i is undef
j is zero
k is empty string
```

Comment: If zero is always `0` you can `if (defined $v and $v eq "0") ..`

Answer (score 4):

Perl does not include a `NULL`, so the line

```
if(@all_num[2]!= NULL)
```

is nonsensical in Perl.  (More accurately, it attempts to locate a `sub` named `NULL` and run it to get the value to compare against `@all_num[2]`, but fails to do so because you (presumably) haven't defined such a `sub`.)  Note that, if you had enabled `use strict`, this would cause a fatal error instead of pretending to work.  This is one of the many reasons to *always* `use strict`.

Side note:  When you pull a value out of an array, it's only a single value, so you should say `$all_num[2]` rather than `@all_num[2]` when referring to the third element of the array `@all_num`.  (Yes, this is a little confusing to get used to.  I hear that it's been changed in Perl 6, but I'm assuming you're using Perl 5 here.)  Note that, if you had enabled `use warnings`, it would have told you that "Scalar value @all_num[2] better written as $all_num[2]".  This is one of the many reasons to *always* `use warnings`.

If you want to test whether `$all_num[2]` contains a value, the proper way to express that in Perl is

```
if (defined $all_num[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how your program would look using best practices

You should

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all your variables with `my`
- Use the three-parameter form of `open`
- Check that `open` calls succeeded, and include `$!` in the `die` string if not
- Use a `while` loop to process a file one line at a time, in preference to reading the entire file into memory

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
while ( <$fh> ) {

  next unless /reftext/;

  my $next_line = <$fh>;
  my @all_num = $next_line =~ /\d+/g;
  print "$all_num[2]\n" if defined $all_num[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open(READFILE, "<", "myfile.txt") or die $!;
my @list = <READFILE>;
my $total_lines = scalar @list;
close (READFILE);

for(my $count=0; $count<$total_lines; $count++)
{
    if($list[$count] =~ /reftext/)
    {
        my @all_num = $list[$count+1] =~ /(\d+)/g;
        if($all_num[2] ne '')
        {
            print "$all_num[2]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

To check a variable is null or not:

```
if ($str ne '')
{
    print $str;
}
```

or better:

```
my ($str);
$str = "";
if (defined($str))
{
    print "defined";
}
else
{
    print "not defined";
}
```

Comment: The OP's use of all-caps "NULL" suggests to me that it's meant to be an SQL-style NULL, in which case testing for empty strings is incorrect, as an empty string is a value, while an SQL NULL is the absence of a value (similar in concept to Perl's `undef`, but with different truthiness semantics).

Comment: @DaveSherohman : Yes, you are right. That is the reason I asked for input data. I am waiting for OP's comment.

Comment: Can I offer - I think your sample code would be improved by a 3 arg open with lexical filehandle.

Comment: @Sobrique : Yeah right. I didn't change that just for OP's understanding. I thought he will get confuse. :)

Comment: @serenesat: Thanks a lot! using ($str ne '') made things work fine. And thanks for the other comments as well, I shall incorporate them.

Comment: @user3477363 : Glad it helped. You can accept this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers do not work, try treating the variable as a string:

```
if ( $all_num[2] == 'null' && length($all_num[2]) == 4 ){
     # null
} else {
     # not null
}
```

As with any code you write, be sure to test your code.